# Rerender When the Slice Viewer Size Is Changed

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I am working on drawing in the sliceViewers, which contains a RenderWindow. But if I enlarge or diminish the window, or change the layout of my module, the drawings become not fit. In other words, the drawing is misplaced when the sliceViewer size is changed.

And what I want is to monitor the size of the sliceViewer in realtime. Once it is changed in any scenrios, I rerender the drawing with the saved data.

I have searched something like observer of vtk or QtObject::connect(), but don't know whether they are really useful or not. Can they help or there is other method?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: is it like your camera is changing the focus from image?

Comment: just resize of the sliceView.
I want real time monitoring of the size of it

Comment: thanks for the reply. Finally, I use an observer with vtkCommand::ModifiedEvent, which triggers the rerendering everytime when there is modification.